# Any fix for AHK (v1.1) latency across rdp connection?

Tags: autohotkey

Much of my work happens on a remote app connected via rdp.  I don't have access to install AHK on the remote server. I have several dozen text macros in AHK that simplify this greatly.  One- or two-word macros work fine; one- or two-liners often get garbled; and paragraph-long macros are hopeless.  They all work fine on my local machine.  For the longer ones, I fire off the macro locally in a notepad window, then copy and paste to the server. This works fine, but is annoying.  I assume the problem is some kind of latency in the connection.  Is there any setting I can tweak to help?  Would upgrading to v2 make a difference?  Up until now I haven't felt the need to upgrade since v1.1 has worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that V2 will help.

If you don't have installation rights on the server, you
could perhaps use portable AutoHotkey by downloading the
[zip version](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/1.1/?C=M;O=D)
and upacking it on the server.